# Cannot install specific version of yum package reported by yum list

Tags: linux, yum, version

I'd like to install with `yum` a specific version of certain packages on an Amazon Linux container. When I list the available versions, I get this:

```
bash-4.2# yum list glibc.i686 tar tcpdump
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
Available Packages
glibc.i686                               2.26-63.amzn2                                  amzn2-core
tar.x86_64                               2:1.26-35.amzn2.0.1                            amzn2-core
tcpdump.x86_64                           14:4.9.2-4.amzn2.1                             amzn2-core
```

But then I cannot install these versions:

```
bash-4.2# yum install glibc.i686-2.26-63.amzn2 tar-2:1.26-35.amzn2.0.1 tcpdump-14:4.9.2-4.amzn2.1
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
No package glibc.i686-2.26-63.amzn2 available.
No package tar-2:1.26-35.amzn2.0.1 available.
No package tcpdump-14:4.9.2-4.amzn2.1 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

However, if I don't specify the versions explicitly, `yum` finds these exact same versions again:

```
bash-4.2# yum install glibc.i686 tar tcpdump
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.26-63.amzn2 will be installed
---> Package tar.x86_64 2:1.26-35.amzn2.0.1 will be installed
---> Package tcpdump.x86_64 14:4.9.2-4.amzn2.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpcap >= 14:1.5.3-10 for package: 14:tcpdump-4.9.2-4.amzn2.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcap.so.1()(64bit) for package: 14:tcpdump-4.9.2-4.amzn2.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libpcap.x86_64 14:1.5.3-11.amzn2 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==========================================================================================================
 Package              Arch                Version                           Repository               Size
==========================================================================================================
Installing:
 glibc                i686                2.26-63.amzn2                     amzn2-core              4.1 M
 tar                  x86_64              2:1.26-35.amzn2.0.1               amzn2-core              845 k
 tcpdump              x86_64              14:4.9.2-4.amzn2.1                amzn2-core              424 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libpcap              x86_64              14:1.5.3-11.amzn2                 amzn2-core              140 k

Transaction Summary
==========================================================================================================
Install  3 Packages (+1 Dependent package)

Total download size: 5.5 M
Installed size: 18 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

This only happens to certain packages, in case of `sudo` or `wget` for example I can install the exact version reported by `yum list`.

For reference, here's the output for `yum search glibc` too:

```
bash-4.2# yum search glibc
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
========================================================================= N/S matched: glibc ==========================================================================
glibc-all-langpacks.x86_64 : All language packs for glibc.
glibc-benchtests.x86_64 : Benchmarking binaries and scripts for glibc
glibc-common.x86_64 : Common binaries and locale data for glibc
glibc-minimal-langpack.x86_64 : Minimal language packs for glibc.
glibc.x86_64 : The GNU libc libraries
glibc.i686 : The GNU libc libraries
glibc-devel.x86_64 : Object files for development using standard C libraries.
glibc-headers.x86_64 : Header files for development using standard C libraries.
glibc-langpack-aa.x86_64 : Locale data for aa
glibc-langpack-af.x86_64 : Locale data for af
glibc-langpack-ak.x86_64 : Locale data for ak
glibc-langpack-am.x86_64 : Locale data for am
glibc-langpack-an.x86_64 : Locale data for an
glibc-langpack-anp.x86_64 : Locale data for anp
glibc-langpack-ar.x86_64 : Locale data for ar
glibc-langpack-as.x86_64 : Locale data for as
glibc-langpack-ast.x86_64 : Locale data for ast
glibc-langpack-ayc.x86_64 : Locale data for ayc
glibc-langpack-az.x86_64 : Locale data for az
glibc-langpack-be.x86_64 : Locale data for be
glibc-langpack-bem.x86_64 : Locale data for bem
glibc-langpack-ber.x86_64 : Locale data for ber
glibc-langpack-bg.x86_64 : Locale data for bg
glibc-langpack-bhb.x86_64 : Locale data for bhb
glibc-langpack-bho.x86_64 : Locale data for bho
glibc-langpack-bn.x86_64 : Locale data for bn
glibc-langpack-bo.x86_64 : Locale data for bo
glibc-langpack-br.x86_64 : Locale data for br
glibc-langpack-brx.x86_64 : Locale data for brx
glibc-langpack-bs.x86_64 : Locale data for bs
glibc-langpack-byn.x86_64 : Locale data for byn
glibc-langpack-ca.x86_64 : Locale data for ca
glibc-langpack-ce.x86_64 : Locale data for ce
glibc-langpack-chr.x86_64 : Locale data for chr
glibc-langpack-cmn.x86_64 : Locale data for cmn
glibc-langpack-crh.x86_64 : Locale data for crh
glibc-langpack-cs.x86_64 : Locale data for cs
glibc-langpack-csb.x86_64 : Locale data for csb
glibc-langpack-cv.x86_64 : Locale data for cv
glibc-langpack-cy.x86_64 : Locale data for cy
glibc-langpack-da.x86_64 : Locale data for da
glibc-langpack-de.x86_64 : Locale data for de
glibc-langpack-doi.x86_64 : Locale data for doi
glibc-langpack-dv.x86_64 : Locale data for dv
glibc-langpack-dz.x86_64 : Locale data for dz
glibc-langpack-el.x86_64 : Locale data for el
glibc-langpack-en.x86_64 : Locale data for en
glibc-langpack-eo.x86_64 : Locale data for eo
glibc-langpack-es.x86_64 : Locale data for es
glibc-langpack-et.x86_64 : Locale data for et
glibc-langpack-eu.x86_64 : Locale data for eu
glibc-langpack-fa.x86_64 : Locale data for fa
glibc-langpack-ff.x86_64 : Locale data for ff
glibc-langpack-fi.x86_64 : Locale data for fi
glibc-langpack-fil.x86_64 : Locale data for fil
glibc-langpack-fo.x86_64 : Locale data for fo
glibc-langpack-fr.x86_64 : Locale data for fr
glibc-langpack-fur.x86_64 : Locale data for fur
glibc-langpack-fy.x86_64 : Locale data for fy
glibc-langpack-ga.x86_64 : Locale data for ga
glibc-langpack-gd.x86_64 : Locale data for gd
glibc-langpack-gez.x86_64 : Locale data for gez
glibc-langpack-gl.x86_64 : Locale data for gl
glibc-langpack-gu.x86_64 : Locale data for gu
glibc-langpack-gv.x86_64 : Locale data for gv
glibc-langpack-ha.x86_64 : Locale data for ha
glibc-langpack-hak.x86_64 : Locale data for hak
glibc-langpack-he.x86_64 : Locale data for he
glibc-langpack-hi.x86_64 : Locale data for hi
glibc-langpack-hne.x86_64 : Locale data for hne
glibc-langpack-hr.x86_64 : Locale data for hr
glibc-langpack-hsb.x86_64 : Locale data for hsb
glibc-langpack-ht.x86_64 : Locale data for ht
glibc-langpack-hu.x86_64 : Locale data for hu
glibc-langpack-hy.x86_64 : Locale data for hy
glibc-langpack-ia.x86_64 : Locale data for ia
glibc-langpack-id.x86_64 : Locale data for id
glibc-langpack-ig.x86_64 : Locale data for ig
glibc-langpack-ik.x86_64 : Locale data for ik
glibc-langpack-is.x86_64 : Locale data for is
glibc-langpack-it.x86_64 : Locale data for it
glibc-langpack-iu.x86_64 : Locale data for iu
glibc-langpack-ja.x86_64 : Locale data for ja
glibc-langpack-ka.x86_64 : Locale data for ka
glibc-langpack-kk.x86_64 : Locale data for kk
glibc-langpack-kl.x86_64 : Locale data for kl
glibc-langpack-km.x86_64 : Locale data for km
glibc-langpack-kn.x86_64 : Locale data for kn
glibc-langpack-ko.x86_64 : Locale data for ko
glibc-langpack-kok.x86_64 : Locale data for kok
glibc-langpack-ks.x86_64 : Locale data for ks
glibc-langpack-ku.x86_64 : Locale data for ku
glibc-langpack-kw.x86_64 : Locale data for kw
glibc-langpack-ky.x86_64 : Locale data for ky
glibc-langpack-lb.x86_64 : Locale data for lb
glibc-langpack-lg.x86_64 : Locale data for lg
glibc-langpack-li.x86_64 : Locale data for li
glibc-langpack-lij.x86_64 : Locale data for lij
glibc-langpack-ln.x86_64 : Locale data for ln
glibc-langpack-lo.x86_64 : Locale data for lo
glibc-langpack-lt.x86_64 : Locale data for lt
glibc-langpack-lv.x86_64 : Locale data for lv
glibc-langpack-lzh.x86_64 : Locale data for lzh
glibc-langpack-mag.x86_64 : Locale data for mag
glibc-langpack-mai.x86_64 : Locale data for mai
glibc-langpack-mg.x86_64 : Locale data for mg
glibc-langpack-mhr.x86_64 : Locale data for mhr
glibc-langpack-mi.x86_64 : Locale data for mi
glibc-langpack-mk.x86_64 : Locale data for mk
glibc-langpack-ml.x86_64 : Locale data for ml
glibc-langpack-mn.x86_64 : Locale data for mn
glibc-langpack-mni.x86_64 : Locale data for mni
glibc-langpack-mr.x86_64 : Locale data for mr
glibc-langpack-ms.x86_64 : Locale data for ms
glibc-langpack-mt.x86_64 : Locale data for mt
glibc-langpack-my.x86_64 : Locale data for my
glibc-langpack-nan.x86_64 : Locale data for nan
glibc-langpack-nb.x86_64 : Locale data for nb
glibc-langpack-nds.x86_64 : Locale data for nds
glibc-langpack-ne.x86_64 : Locale data for ne
glibc-langpack-nhn.x86_64 : Locale data for nhn
glibc-langpack-niu.x86_64 : Locale data for niu
glibc-langpack-nl.x86_64 : Locale data for nl
glibc-langpack-nn.x86_64 : Locale data for nn
glibc-langpack-nr.x86_64 : Locale data for nr
glibc-langpack-nso.x86_64 : Locale data for nso
glibc-langpack-oc.x86_64 : Locale data for oc
glibc-langpack-om.x86_64 : Locale data for om
glibc-langpack-or.x86_64 : Locale data for or
glibc-langpack-os.x86_64 : Locale data for os
glibc-langpack-pa.x86_64 : Locale data for pa
glibc-langpack-pap.x86_64 : Locale data for pap
glibc-langpack-pl.x86_64 : Locale data for pl
glibc-langpack-ps.x86_64 : Locale data for ps
glibc-langpack-pt.x86_64 : Locale data for pt
glibc-langpack-quz.x86_64 : Locale data for quz
glibc-langpack-raj.x86_64 : Locale data for raj
glibc-langpack-ro.x86_64 : Locale data for ro
glibc-langpack-ru.x86_64 : Locale data for ru
glibc-langpack-rw.x86_64 : Locale data for rw
glibc-langpack-sa.x86_64 : Locale data for sa
glibc-langpack-sat.x86_64 : Locale data for sat
glibc-langpack-sc.x86_64 : Locale data for sc
glibc-langpack-sd.x86_64 : Locale data for sd
glibc-langpack-se.x86_64 : Locale data for se
glibc-langpack-sgs.x86_64 : Locale data for sgs
glibc-langpack-shs.x86_64 : Locale data for shs
glibc-langpack-si.x86_64 : Locale data for si
glibc-langpack-sid.x86_64 : Locale data for sid
glibc-langpack-sk.x86_64 : Locale data for sk
glibc-langpack-sl.x86_64 : Locale data for sl
glibc-langpack-so.x86_64 : Locale data for so
glibc-langpack-sq.x86_64 : Locale data for sq
glibc-langpack-sr.x86_64 : Locale data for sr
glibc-langpack-ss.x86_64 : Locale data for ss
glibc-langpack-st.x86_64 : Locale data for st
glibc-langpack-sv.x86_64 : Locale data for sv
glibc-langpack-sw.x86_64 : Locale data for sw
glibc-langpack-szl.x86_64 : Locale data for szl
glibc-langpack-ta.x86_64 : Locale data for ta
glibc-langpack-tcy.x86_64 : Locale data for tcy
glibc-langpack-te.x86_64 : Locale data for te
glibc-langpack-tg.x86_64 : Locale data for tg
glibc-langpack-th.x86_64 : Locale data for th
glibc-langpack-the.x86_64 : Locale data for the
glibc-langpack-ti.x86_64 : Locale data for ti
glibc-langpack-tig.x86_64 : Locale data for tig
glibc-langpack-tk.x86_64 : Locale data for tk
glibc-langpack-tl.x86_64 : Locale data for tl
glibc-langpack-tn.x86_64 : Locale data for tn
glibc-langpack-tr.x86_64 : Locale data for tr
glibc-langpack-ts.x86_64 : Locale data for ts
glibc-langpack-tt.x86_64 : Locale data for tt
glibc-langpack-ug.x86_64 : Locale data for ug
glibc-langpack-uk.x86_64 : Locale data for uk
glibc-langpack-unm.x86_64 : Locale data for unm
glibc-langpack-ur.x86_64 : Locale data for ur
glibc-langpack-uz.x86_64 : Locale data for uz
glibc-langpack-ve.x86_64 : Locale data for ve
glibc-langpack-vi.x86_64 : Locale data for vi
glibc-langpack-wa.x86_64 : Locale data for wa
glibc-langpack-wae.x86_64 : Locale data for wae
glibc-langpack-wal.x86_64 : Locale data for wal
glibc-langpack-wo.x86_64 : Locale data for wo
glibc-langpack-xh.x86_64 : Locale data for xh
glibc-langpack-yi.x86_64 : Locale data for yi
glibc-langpack-yo.x86_64 : Locale data for yo
glibc-langpack-yue.x86_64 : Locale data for yue
glibc-langpack-zh.x86_64 : Locale data for zh
glibc-langpack-zu.x86_64 : Locale data for zu
glibc-locale-source.x86_64 : The sources for the locales
glibc-nss-devel.x86_64 : Development files for directly linking NSS service modules
glibc-static.x86_64 : C library static libraries for -static linking.
glibc-utils.x86_64 : Development utilities from GNU C library
kernel-headers.x86_64 : Header files for the Linux kernel for use by glibc
latrace.x86_64 : LD_AUDIT feature frontend for glibc 2.4+
latrace.i686 : LD_AUDIT feature frontend for glibc 2.4+

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the formatted output of `yum search glibc`?

Comment: @Ramhound I've added the output to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials and errors I figured out that adding the architecture **after the version** solves the problem:

```
bash-4.2# yum install glibc-2.26-63.amzn2.i686 tar-2:1.26-35.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 tcpdump-14:4.9.2-4.amzn2.1.x86_64
\Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.26-63.amzn2 will be installed
---> Package tar.x86_64 2:1.26-35.amzn2.0.1 will be installed
---> Package tcpdump.x86_64 14:4.9.2-4.amzn2.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpcap >= 14:1.5.3-10 for package: 14:tcpdump-4.9.2-4.amzn2.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcap.so.1()(64bit) for package: 14:tcpdump-4.9.2-4.amzn2.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libpcap.x86_64 14:1.5.3-11.amzn2 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=======================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                             Arch                               Version                                           Repository                              Size
=======================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 glibc                               i686                               2.26-63.amzn2                                     amzn2-core                             4.1 M
 tar                                 x86_64                             2:1.26-35.amzn2.0.1                               amzn2-core                             845 k
 tcpdump                             x86_64                             14:4.9.2-4.amzn2.1                                amzn2-core                             424 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libpcap                             x86_64                             14:1.5.3-11.amzn2                                 amzn2-core                             140 k

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================================================================================================
Install  3 Packages (+1 Dependent package)

Total download size: 5.5 M
Installed size: 18 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

For `glibc.i686` it may have been my fault of putting the version number ahead of the architecture from the beginning. For the other two packages I'm not sure about the exact reason, but I guess the problem is there are too many dots in the version number and it confuses `yum`. It probably believes the `0.1` part of `amzn2.0.1` is the architecture.